# C# Click an verify link in an temp email website

Tags: c#, html

I'm writing a little application that automates the creation of an account. I use the website http://temp-mail.org for the email adress generation.

Currently with my code the log suggests that the links have been clicked, but this isn't the case. First issue that I have is upon registration there are 3 email send and that results in the following HTML code. Problem both have no id's, only difference is the "title-subject".

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>"PlayStation Network" &lt;sony@email.sonyentertainmentnetwork.com&gt;</td>
        <td>
            <a href="http://temp-mail.org/en/view/e9527b19d5db504182428bac583977fe"
               class="title-subject">Controleer je account.</a>
        </td>
        <td>...</td>
        <td class="text-center">
            <a href="http://temp-mail.org/en/view/e9527b19d5db504182428bac583977fe"
               class="link">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>"PlayStation Network" &lt;Sony@email.sonyentertainmentnetwork.com&gt;</td>
        <td>
            <a href="http://temp-mail.org/en/view/d3b3a892daeb5c99d85f4c5999242664"
               class="title-subject">Je gebruikersnaam is bijg</a>
        </td>
        <td>...</td>
        <td class="text-center">
            <a href="http://temp-mail.org/en/view/d3b3a892daeb5c99d85f4c5999242664"
               class="link">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

In the email there is a link that has to be clicked and that one has the following HTML

```
<td align="center"
    width="150"
    height="40"
    bgcolor="#3071a3"
    style="-webkit-border-radius: 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px; color: #ffffff; display: block;">
    <a href="https://account.sonyentertainmentnetwork.com/liquid/cam/account/email/validate-email.action?service-entity=np&amp;token=YTVhOTc4ZjItMDI230F3cH9ehcugYxy%2BC9YWHgnQ8l8lh2v%2F943yVVYQWQS4XUlJNMHt0cUlVMpBGAdc7TcwraMoF8K6CQr5QsfaDknPNIgmmWUGyM%2FcEF67%2BHk%3D&amp;request_locale=nl_NL"
       style="color: #ffffff; font-size:16px; font-weight: bold; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:18px; text-decoration: none; line-height:40px; width:100%; display:inline-block">Nu bevestigen</a>
</td>
```

Now I tried with the following code:

```
void DoConfirmation()
        {
            Log("Verifying Email...");
            NavigateAndWait("http://temp-mail.org");
            bool RecievedConfEmail = false;

            for (;;)
            {
                if (!RecievedConfEmail)
                {
                    HtmlElementCollection links = _WebDocument.GetElementsByTagName("A");

                    foreach (HtmlElement link in links)
                    {
                        if (link.InnerText.Equals("account"))
                            link.InvokeMember("Click");
                        Log("I clicked that email you asked");
                        RecievedConfEmail = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    HtmlElementCollection links = _WebDocument.GetElementsByTagName("A");

                    foreach (HtmlElement link in links)
                    {
                        if (link.InnerText.Equals("Bevestigen"))
                            link.InvokeMember("Click");
                        Log("I clicked IN the Email #2");
                        return;
                    }
                }
                Wait(25);
            }
        }
```

So I tried the catch the first right email by searching for the word "account" and in the second one with the word "bevestigen". Even though the log shows me that the links have been click this is not the case.

Can someone help me out with a more clever and robust manner to catch the right email and click the link?

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're logging even if `InnerText` doesn't equal (`account` or `Bevstigen`). Look at your if blocks. You also exit the `foreach` and thus only look at a single link. Use `{}` after both `if` statements. For example:

```
foreach (HtmlElement link in links)
{
    if (link.InnerText.Equals("account"))
    {
        link.InvokeMember("Click");
        Log("I clicked that email you asked");
        RecievedConfEmail = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

```
foreach (HtmlElement link in links)
{
    if (link.InnerText.Equals("Bevestigen"))
    {
        link.InvokeMember("Click");
        Log("I clicked IN the Email #2");
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this "fixed" the false positive's from clicking the link, and confirms why it's not confirmed. Although i cannot figure out why it's not matching the HTML and not clicking the link.

Comment: @Senaxx Try `InnerText.Contains` rather than `InnerText.Equals`. You're currently running `"Nu bevestigen" == "Bevestigen"` which is false. Also be aware of case sensitivity.